# How to store locators in a sepearate file in nightwatch.js

Tags: javascript, selenium, nightwatch.js

I was going through some Automation Testing using Nightwatch.js. And, i wanted to store my CSS locators in a separate file, so that i can easily modify them, when needed. But, i want to use these locators in another file inside the page folder only and not in the main test script. 
According to the documentation, it is possible to use these locators in the main test file, but, i couldn't find a way to use it in another pages function.
My locators are as follows:

```
    module.exports=     {
                elements: {
                            usernameCSS: 'input[name=username]',
                            passwordCSS: 'input[name=password]',
                            signInButton: 'input[value="Sign in"]',
                            warningText: '.text-danger'             
                            }
                };
```

And the file in which i want to use it is as follows:

```
    var commonFunctions = require("./commonFunctions.js");
    var locators = require("./locators.js");
    module.exports = function(browser) {
    var common = new commonFunctions(browser);

/*
 * Test specific functions
  */

this.signIn = function(locators) {
    common.clickUsingCss('@signInButton');
    return browser;
};
this.inputUserName = function(value) {
     common.inputValue('@usernameCSS', value);
    return browser;
};
 this.inputPassword = function(value)   {
    common.inputValue('@passwordCSS', value);
    return browser;
};
```